# What is Default value of array on heap in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, heap-memory

When I print the default value of array on heap memory I'm getting random big numbers in code block. I know that the default value of array is 0 but I am getting random number .

Comment: Can you provide a sample code to show your problem ?

Comment: This will depend on your compiler, compiler options and platform on which it runs.

Comment: Please show some code, I'm not sure what you mean by "default value of array". Array of what?

Comment: To be pedantic, it is called free store, not heap. C++ is designed for abstract hardware.

Comment: In a release build of C++, the values in variables are generally undefined, and don't have specified defaults.

Comment: There are no "default values" for arrays on the heap. `static` arrays are explicitly zero-initialized. Everything else's default is random garbage.

Comment: `int* p = new int[10];` then p[0..9] contain indeterminate values. There is no default.

Answer (score 1):

The [doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) of the std::array constructor says it:

> initializes the array following the rules of aggregate initialization (note that default initialization may result in indeterminate values for non-class T)